# Crontab - sh: ip command not found

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip, cron

I have a php script that can successfully get the results of this command.

```
exec("ip addr list",$results);
```

if I run it on command line using

```
/usr/bin/php /root/myscript.php
```

but when crontab will make it run, it will result to sh: ip command not found.
i also tried

```
exec("/sbin/ip addr list",$results);
```

but still no luck

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a log to your cronjob to see what might go wrong, e.g.;

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
14 9 1 8 * /usr/bin/php /home/user/test.php >> /home/user/test.log 2>&1
```

Below code got executed successfully with a cronjob;

```
<?php
$ret = exec("/sbin/ip addr list", $out, $err);
$file = '/home/user/output.log';
file_put_contents($file, $out);
?>
```